# Design in table in pdf with jspdf?

Tags: html, html-table, pdf-generation, jspdf

I want to copy exactly this table to PDF with jspdf.

[image]

But jspdf prints me this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<style>
table#disenio{
    border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; background: #CCC; color: #A41E15;
}
table#disenio td, table#disenio th{
    border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; background: #CCC; color: #A41E15;
}
```

```
<table id="disenio">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>HolaU</th>
        <th>HolaU</th>
        <th>HolaU</th>
        <th>HolaU</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
        <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="button">Run Code</a>
```

Js's:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>               
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
```

Js Code:

```
<script>
 function demoFromHTML() {
     var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML(
    $('#disenio').get(0), 15, 15, {
'width': 170
});

     doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}
```

Please, help me! What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jsPDF table feature is very basic and basically first converts the html table to json and then creates a table from that. Some styling might be copied over but it is hit or miss really. If you want a styled table a better option is to use a table plugin to jsPDF and specify the styling manually.

EDIT: I made my own [table plugin](https://github.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable) for jsPDF featuring auto width and a bunch of other features.